# How to see the ring of all  polynomials (with integer coefficients) that are bounded on a given real algebraic set?

Tags: nt.number-theory

Let $S$ be the zero set in $\mathbb{R}^n$ of a polynomial with real coefficients. Let $B$ 
be the ring of polynomials, with INTEGER coefficients, that are bounded on $S$.

I would like to know how to get basic information about $B$: When is $B=\mathbb{Z}$? When is $B$ finitely generated? How do I find some comprehensible set of ring generators of $B$?  Any suggestions or references would be appreciated.

Comment: Someone care to explain the vote to close?  This seems like a perfectly reasonable question to me.  

Comment: This is a comment. I might not be as comfortable with the notation, but if $B$ is a ring of polynomials, how can $B = \mathbb Z$? Is $B$ also in $\mathbb R^n$? Can you provide more details on why $B$ is always a ring, as opposed to just a set of polynomials? Finally, what do you mean for a polynomial to be bounded by a set?

Comment: @Wlog: the question is clear. B is "the ring of polynomials with integer coefficients that happen to have property X" which I think is perfectly clear. If no non-constant polynomials have property X then B is the integers. Being "bounded on S" means that there is a constant C such that |p(s)|<=C for all s in S.

Comment: @Wlog:  A polynomial $p$ is "bounded" on a subset $S$ of $\mathbb{R}^n$ if for some real $r$, the inequality `$|p(x)| < r$` holds for every $x$ in $S$. 

 How could $B=\mathbb{Z}$? For example, consider the line $y=\pi x$ in $\mathbb{R}^2$.  If a non-constant polynomial $f(x,y)$ with integer coefficients was bounded on that line, then $f(x,\pi x)$ would reduce to a constant, which would imply that $pi$ is rational.  So in this case $B=\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: @Kevin: We posted simultaneously.

Comment: Some random comments. (a) this is "not a proper question", like I always say: B=Z precisely when it's Z, for example. But on the other hand it feels like it has potential. As you say as a comment in Wlog's answer, if S={y=pi.x} then B=Z. But it's not true that if S is not defined over Q-bar then B=Z: for example if S={y=pi} then f(x,pi) had better be constant so B=Z[y]. Is B always finitely-generated? That's a question. Do you know a counterexample? Aah---if S={y=0} then f(x,0) had better be constant so B might well be Z[y,xy,x^2y,...]---is that right? And that's not f.g.. 

Comment: In fact here's a better example: if S={x^2+y^2=pi} then certainly S isn't defined over Q-bar but B is everything.

Comment: @Kevin: Why is question not proper? Because I'm speaking as if the embedding of $\mathbb{Z}$ in $\mathbb{Z}[x]$ is an inclusion? Isn't this a common and convenient  and utterly harmless manner of speaking? Please consider editing out your "not proper" comment, unless you have  other objections. I would hate to loose some potential comment or answer.

Comment: There are some things that seem odd in the formulation of the 
question. If you are want the polynomials in B to have 
integer coefficients, surely you also want to the polynomial defining 
S to have integer coefficients? Also, if g and 
h have the same restriction to S, are they the same or different as elements 
of B? I assumed they were the same; if you want them to be different 
then your ring will almost never be finitely generated because of examples 
like `S={x=0}`.

Comment: @ David Speyer I'd be  happy to have an answer in the case that $S$ is defined  by polynomials with integer coefficients.   By $B$ I mean polynomials, formal objects, not functions on $S$..... And yes, non-finite-generation would seem to be typical, but I can't pin down exact conditions on $S$. Some background:  Finding non-constant elements of $B$ is the crux of Runge's Theorem on Diophantine equations (cf Sprindzuk's Classical Diophantine Equations, Ch 1.)
I want to generalize this theorem to equations of more than 2 variables.

Comment: For that you need them to be nonconstant as functions on B. You can always find a polynomial which is nonconstant on R^n and bounded on S -- namely, the polynomial that defines S!

Comment: Are you thinking that if $S$ is defined by a polynomial equation with integer coefficients, then all bounded polynomials on $S$ are constant? This is not true -- For example if $S$ is defined by the polynomial equation equivalent to $y-x=\frac{1}{1+x^2}$, then $y-x$ is bounded but not constant on $S$. The situation in $>2$ variables seems harder, since one can't just write out and analyse finitely many Puiseux series representing the branches at infinity of $S$.

Comment: @anon: it's "not a proper question" because it is not of the form "prove this", it's of the form "give me necessary and sufficient conditions for this", so a logically valid but unhelpful answer would be "B=Z iff B=Z".

Comment: @David: don't my examples convince you that S not being defined over Z can still give a wealth of interesting possibilities?

Comment: @David, Kevin: Here's an example where S is not defined over Z: Fix algebraically independent reals r and  s, and take S to be the subset of R^3 defined by (y-2^(1/2)x+r)^2+(z-8^(1/2)rx+s)^2=0. Then the polynomial y^2-2x^2+z is bounded on S. I don't see any systematic way to deduce all results like this!

Answer (score 1):

Let $\bar{S}$ by the closure of *S* in $\mathbb{P}^n(\mathbb{R})$. If a polynomial with zero constant term is bounded on *S*, then its highest degree term vanishes on $S':=\bar{S} \setminus S \subset \mathbb{P}^{n-1}$. In particular, if *S'* is Zariski dense in $\mathbb{P}^{n-1}$ **over Z**, then *B=Z* (classically, sets with similar properties were called "generic"). On the other hand, *S'* could be defined over $\overline{\mathbb{Q}}$ even when *S* is not (e.g. $y^2=\pi x$).

Since obviously $B \neq \mathbb{Z}$ in the case in which $B \neq \mathbb{R}^n$ and *B* is defined over $\overline{\mathbb{Q}}$, it would be interesting to find an irreducible *S* not defined over $\overline{\mathbb{Q}}$ which is unbounded (i.e. $S' \neq \emptyset$) and for which $B \neq \mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: Yes! An example I gave (way below) maybe does the job: Fix algebraically independent reals r and s, and take S to be the subset of R^3 defined by 
(y-2^(1/2)x+r)^2+(z-8^(1/2)rx+s)^2=0. Then the polynomial y^2-2x^2+z is bounded on S. (I assume you mean irreducible over R.)

Comment: Your example works for what I asked, even though I would have wanted an example in the *n=2* case. Also, the ideal of all polynomials vanishing on the *S* you described is generated by the two linear terms in the equation (you do not care about non-reducedness, nor about complex points). In your case, the "trace at infinity" of *S* is contained in the vanishing set of *y-sqrt(2)x* and it is maybe $\mathbb{Z}$-dense in there. I would have wanted an example which is "genuinely" not defined over $\mathbb{Q}$: in some sense, the example you gave has one "side" defined over *Q* and one which isn't.